# PyInstaller exe only works when run from cmd

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I'm trying to pack a python tool I wrote into an exe file for use on Windows 10. As far as I know, the exe is built correctly. It loads and everything works if I run it from the command line.

However, if I try to run the tool from Explorer (double-clicking the icon), I get a "Failed to execute script" error. I've tried building it using the --debug switch, hoping that I could quickly catch any output before cmd closes, but it's just too fast.

The line I use to build the tool is:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --debug --console --icon=C:\Users\Ross\Desktop\gtt\assets\icon.ico --hidden-import xlrd gtt.py
```

It worked perfectly before I began using the reportlab modules:

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_CENTER
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, portrait
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph, Spacer
```

The command line gives absolutely no output regarding errors when I run it using the debug switch:
[image: Screenshot showing tool running in cmd]

I've tried the following and nothing has worked.

- --noupx
- --onedir
- --onefile

To sum it up, why would a PyInstaller exe file work when run from the command line, but not from the Windows GUI?

**EDIT: The issue seems to be with PyQt4. I went back to a commit where I switch from tkinter to Qt and the issue is still there. The previous build, with tkinter, loads fine from the GUI.**

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

I had to convert the gui.ui file into a package.

1. I created the package "gui," containing an empty __init__.py
2. I ran `pyuic4 gui.ui -o gui.py`to convert the gui.ui code into Python
3. I moved both gui.ui and gui.py files into the gui directory
4. In my main program code, I imported the module: `from gui.gui import *`

Hope that helps anyone else!